# Removing the margin from the last item in a list

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net, sharepoint

I have margin set for my list tabs but however the last item also gets the margin. when my last item is active the background color doesn't fill the whole space.

Asking For Help

here is my code

```
  <div id="tabcontainer">
<ul class="tabcontentnav">
    <li class="tabactive">  <a href="#tab1">For Parents, Patients &amp Caregivers</a>

    </li>
    <li>    <a href="#tab2">For Researchers</a>

    </li>
    <li>    <a href="#tab3">For Health Care Providers</a>

    </li>
    <li>    <a href="#tab4">For EducatorsFor</a>

    </li>
    <li>    <a href="#tab5">For Small Business</a>

    </li>
</ul>
<section id="tab1" class="tab-content tabactive">
    <div>Content in tab 1</div>
</section>
<section id="tab2" class="tab-content hide">
    <div>Content in tab 2</div>
</section>
<section id="tab3" class="tab-content hide">
    <div>Content in tab 3</div>
</section>
<section id="tab4" class="tab-content hide">
    <div>Content in tab 4</div>
</section>
<section id="tab5" class="tab-content hide">
    <div>Content in tab 5</div>
</section>
```

```
css 


#tabcontainer {
background: white;
border: 1px solid;
border-radius: 10px;
min-height: 200px;
 }

.tabcontentnav {
margin-left: 0;
list-style: none;
max-height: 30px;
padding-left: 0px;
margin-top: 12px;
color:black;
border-bottom: 3px solid #BEDCF2;
padding-bottom: 10px;
}   
.tabcontentnav li {
display: inline;
 }    
.tabcontentnav > li > a {
padding:12px;
margin-right:3px;
color: black;
text-decoration: none;
}
 .tabcontentnav > li > a:hover {
background-color: #BEDCF2;
border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
}
  .tabcontentnav > .tabactive > a, .tabcontentnav > .tabactive > a:hover {
color: #555555;
cursor: default;
background-color: #BEDCF2;
border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
}
.tab-content.tabactive {
display: block;
border-top: 1px solid;
margin-top: -12px;
padding: 10px;
}    
.tab-content.hide {
display: none;
}
```

more is on this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5j49quzx/18/

Comment: Which browser are you looking at? seems to be okay in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [:last-child pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child) to change the margin on the last tab:

```
.tabcontentnav > li:last-child > a {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

Here's [your fiddle with the added style](http://jsfiddle.net/5j49quzx/20/).

Comment: There is no more margin on the last tab, so that issue *has* been fixed. Instead your #tabcontainer is too wide. At 770 pixels wide you don't have enough tab to fill it up to the end; a completely separate issue. You should look into sizing it dynamically (for a start, try floating it).

Answer (score 0):

The `:last-child` pseudoclass is what you're looking for. Here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5j49quzx/19/

`:last-child` is just about universally supported these days: http://caniuse.com/#search=last-child

In your case, you need to target `<a>` elements that are inside the last `<li>` element:

```
.tabcontentnav > li:last-child > a {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change the code to use adjacent selectors:

```
.tabcontentnav li a {
     /* margin-right: 3px; == remove this line */
}

.tabcontentnav li + li {
     margin-right: 3px;
}
```

That way, only list items that are followed by another list item will have the `margin` settled.

More information about adjacent sibling selectors: https://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/

Comment: @user388969 That's an valid alternative, just be aware that IE8 doesn't support `:last-child`.

Comment: SAW THAT now new issue. IE-8 doesn't support the border-radius either...such a pain browser

Comment: @user388969 IE8 has support for adjacent selectors (`li + li`), so my answer is right. As for `border-radius`, you shouldn't be preoccupied over this and use the progressive enhancement approach.